# Dojo : How to make PUT request on jsonRest store with callback method

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

I'm using Dojo JsonREST store to communicate with a RESTful API on the server. The GET and QUERY methods work very well, with asynchronous callback handlers.  The PUT request to post new object on the JsonREST store however doesn't seem to have asynchronous callback capabilities.  It is then impossible to fire an event only if the PUT request was done and was a success.

From the documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) :

```
 require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRestStore){
     var store = new JsonRestStore({target: "/Table/" });

     store.get(3).then(function(object){
        // CALLBACK HERE :-)
     });

     store.query("foo=bar").then(function(results){
       // CALLBACK HERE :-)
     });

     store.put({ foo: "bar" }, { id: 3 }); // NO CALLBACK CAPABILITIES ???

     store.remove(3); // NO CALLBACK CAPABILITIES ???
});
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `store.put({ foo: "bar" }, { id: 3 }).then(function(){});`, `store.remove(3).then(function(){});` ? Check [these docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) and [this post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/32931-How-to-use-dojo.Deferred-dojo.DeferredList-and-.then).

Comment: You are right. A look at the source code reveals that the returned object is a Deferred.  However, a bug (supposed to be fixed in Dojo 1.8) make it impossible to get back the header response, like this : `store.put({ foo: "bar" }, { id: 3 }).then(function(message, ioArgs){});` Here, `ioArgs` will be undefined.

Comment: var deferred = put(item); will get you back the deferred object, then you can add a callback and access the xhr object in ioArgs like: def.addCallback(function(mess,io){
                                console.log(io);
                                console.log(mess);
                                console.log(def.ioArgs.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                            });

Answer (score 1):

```
put: function(object, options){
    // summary:
    //      Stores an object. This will trigger a PUT request to the server
    //      if the object has an id, otherwise it will trigger a POST request.
    // object: Object
    //      The object to store.
    // options: dojo.store.api.Store.PutDirectives?
    //      Additional metadata for storing the data.  Includes an "id"
    //      property if a specific id is to be used.
    //  returns: Number
      ....
      return xhr( ....);
    }
```

The documentation is wrong, return is infact a dojo.Deferred as just stated.

Expect function prototype to read function(responseText, ioArgs)

Comment: You are right. However, as I mentioned in another comment, a bug (supposed to be fixed in Dojo 1.8) make it impossible to get back the header response, like this : `store.put({ foo: "bar" }, { id: 3 }).then(function(message, ioArgs){});` Here, `ioArgs` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The dojo documentation states that for adding a new item you should use POST, as PUT is for updating the store.